# Saving login location into the database of my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoder

When I sign into the application, the code below gets called. So inside the SessionsController, SignupHistory table gets populated with the `.create` method.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user
  before_action :set_timezone, :current_country

  def current_country
    if session[:ip_country_code].present?
      return @current_country = session[:ip_country_code]
    end
    use_default = request.location.nil? || request.location.country_code.blank? || request.location.country_code == 'RD'
    country_code = use_default ? ENV['DEFAULT_IP_COUNTRY_CODE'] : request.location.country_code
    @current_country = session[:ip_country_code] = country_code
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def save_signup_history(member_id)
    SignupHistory.create(
      member_id: member_id,
      ip: request.ip,
      accept_language: request.headers["Accept-Language"],
      ua: request.headers["User-Agent"],
      login_location: request.location
    )
  end
end
```

**database attributes**

[image: databse]

However, instead of the line `login_location: request.location` to write the location of the IP signing in into the database such as `New York`, what I get in the database is:

> --- !ruby/object:Geocoder::Result::Ipstack data: ip: 127.0.0.1 country_name: Reserved country_code: RD cache_hit:

**How do I save location based on the IP signing in into my database**

Comment: What does the `request` contain?

Comment: Honestly I don't even know, neither do I know how to check what `request` contain.

Comment: Just do `raise request.inspect` inside the `save_signup_history` method and paste the output in the question

Comment: Is this data from you accessing your app via localhost?

Comment: Yes from localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.remote_ip` to get the IP address.
TO get the location of IP address saved in DB, you can use one of the free API services that fetch location information based on IP:
 - http://ip-api.com/
 - https://www.iplocation.net/
 - etc..

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

  def save_signup_history(member_id)
    SignupHistory.create(
        member_id: member_id,
        ip: request.ip,
        accept_language: request.headers["Accept-Language"],
        ua: request.headers["User-Agent"],
        login_location: get_address(request.remote_ip)
    )
  end


#http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201
  def get_address(ip)
    url = "http://ip-api.com/json/#{ip}"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    result = JSON.parse(response)
    result["regionName"] # returns region name 
  end
end
```

**JSON Response:**

```
{
"as":"AS14907 Wikimedia Foundation, Inc.",
"city":"San Francisco (South Beach)",
"country":"United States",
"countryCode":"US",
"isp":"Wikimedia Foundation, Inc.",
"lat":37.787,
"lon":-122.4,
"org":"Wikimedia Foundation, Inc.",
"query":"208.80.152.201",
"region":"",
"regionName":"California",
"status":"success",
"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles",
"zip":"94105"
}
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/remote_ip

Comment: But I already have the IP save into the database using `ip: request.ip`. Am trying to get location such as you signin in from New York, and it records New York, and if signing in from London, it records London

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi I thought you are having issue with IP as I can you are showing localhost IP

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi you need to use a service like https://www.iplocation.net/ to get the location of IP addresses you have

Comment: Can you show example using iplocation.net without loosing my request params fro the id?

Comment: okay I see your very beautiful update. Thank you. So, if I need to return `regionName` and `country` I can do `result["regionName"] && result["country"]` ? Such that I can have `New York, United States` saved in the database.

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi you can change last line from `result["regionName"]` to `"#{result['country']},#{result['regionName']}"`

Comment: Yes I surely will do that. Thank you so much.